# Help with SSJS Complex Filter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I've been working on the filter below but it does not return any result. Can you guys please tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Goal is to find a record where `ClientId_Boxhill = CenterClientID OR ( FirstName=CenterFirstName AND Surname=CenterSurname AND MobilePhone=CenterMobilePhone AND MobilePhone!=null AND MobilePhone !="61400000000" )`

**Version A**

```javascript
var filterc2 = {
    LeftOperand: {
        Property: "CliendId_Boxhill",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: CenterClientId
    },

    LogicalOperator: "OR",

    RightOperand: {
        LeftOperand: {
            Property: "FirstName",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: CenterFirstName
        },

        LogicalOperator: "AND",

        RightOperand: {
            LeftOperand: {
            Property: "Surname",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: CenterSurname
            },

            LogicalOperator: "AND",

            RightOperand: {
                LeftOperand: {
                    Property: "MobilePhone",
                    SimpleOperator: "isNotNull"
                },

                LogicalOperator: "AND",

                RightOperand: {
                    LeftOperand: {
                        Property: "MobilePhone",
                        SimpleOperator: "notEquals",
                        Value: "61400000000"
                    },

                    LogicalOperator: "AND",

                    RightOperand: {
                        Property:"MobilePhone",
                        SimpleOperator: "equals",
                        Value: CenterMobilePhone
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Version B**

```javascript
var filter1 = {
    LeftOperand: {
        Property: "FirstName",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: CenterFirstName
    },

    LogicalOperator: "AND",
    RightOperand: {
        LeftOperand: {
        Property: "Surname",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: CenterSurname
        },

        LogicalOperator: "AND",

        RightOperand: {
            Property: "MobilePhone",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: CenterMobilePhone
        }
    }
};

var filter2 = {
    LeftOperand: {
        Property: "MobilePhone",
        SimpleOperator: "isNotNull"
    },

    LogicalOperator: "AND",
    
    RightOperand: {
        Property: "MobilePhone",
        SimpleOperator: "notEquals",
        Value: "61400000000"
    }
};

var filter3 = {
    LeftOperand: filter1,
    LogicalOperator: "AND",
    RightOperand: filter2
};

var filterc2 = {
    LeftOperand: filter3,
    LogicalOperator: "OR",
    RightOperand: {
        Property: "CliendId_Boxhill",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: CenterClientId
    }
};
```

Comment: there is a typo in both versions: "CliendId_Boxhill"

Comment: Ohh. thanks. I didn't even notice that. Will fix it and hopefully it would work